Getting The Visual Bounds of a Node
I'm trying to make a custom border for a text field. I used the boundsInParentProperty to make the border. However, these bounds behave like a bounding box which aren't suitable for my case. The following is a snapshot of the text field with the border:

The problems arise when the node is rotated, the following is another snapshot when the text field is rotated:

This is a sample code:
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.LineTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.scene.shape.PathElement;
import javafx.scene.transform.Scale;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public class CustomBorder extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField textField = new TextField("Hello, World!");
        textField.setStyle("-fx-padding: 8; -fx-max-width: 20; -fx-font-size: 18;" +
                "-fx-border-insets: 0; -fx-background-insets: 0; -fx-background-radius: 0; " +
                "-fx-border-style: none; -fx-background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5); -fx-min-width: 140");

        textField.setRotate(-25);


        Path border = new Path();
        border.getElements().addAll(createBorder(textField, BorderLine.LEFT));
        border.getElements().addAll(createBorder(textField, BorderLine.TOP));
        border.getElements().addAll(createBorder(textField, BorderLine.RIGHT));
        border.getElements().addAll(createBorder(textField, BorderLine.BOTTOM));
        border.setManaged(false);
        border.setViewOrder(0);

        HBox root = new HBox(textField, border);
        root.setBackground(Background.fill(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        root.getTransforms().add(new Scale(2, 2));
        root.relocate(100, 100);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Custom Border");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 400));
        primaryStage.show();

        root.requestFocus();
    }

    @NotNull
    private PathElement[] createBorder(Region region, @NotNull BorderLine borderLine) {
        MoveTo moveTo = new MoveTo();
        LineTo lineTo = new LineTo();
        switch (borderLine) {
            case LEFT -> region.boundsInParentProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                moveTo.setX(newValue.getMinX());
                moveTo.setY(newValue.getMinY());
                lineTo.setX(newValue.getMinX());
                lineTo.setY(newValue.getMaxY());
            });
            case TOP -> region.boundsInParentProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                moveTo.setX(newValue.getMinX());
                moveTo.setY(newValue.getMinY());
                lineTo.setX(newValue.getMaxX());
                lineTo.setY(newValue.getMinY());
            });
            case RIGHT -> region.boundsInParentProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                moveTo.setX(newValue.getMaxX());
                moveTo.setY(newValue.getMinY());
                lineTo.setX(newValue.getMaxX());
                lineTo.setY(newValue.getMaxY());
            });
            case BOTTOM -> region.boundsInParentProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                moveTo.setX(newValue.getMinX());
                moveTo.setY(newValue.getMaxY());
                lineTo.setX(newValue.getMaxX());
                lineTo.setY(newValue.getMaxY());
            });
        }

        return new PathElement[]{moveTo, lineTo};
    }

    public enum BorderLine {
        LEFT, RIGHT, TOP, BOTTOM;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

How can I make the border have the correct x/y values?

@Abra yes, I want the border to rotate with the node. How come I post the thing that I am asking for? :)

@Abra I think the definition of a "border" would give you a visual representation of what i want.

You didn't need to get the visual bounds of the node to solve your problem, but if you did in the future, you can apply CSS and generate a layout pass.

I'm confused by this.  There's nothing in this custom border that cannot be done via CSS or programmatic addition of a border to the TextField or the HBox.  So why do this?

@DaveB I'm planning to add more border styles using SVG; hence the usage of Path class.

Unrelated to the question topic, but given your objective, consider using an SVGPath instead of a Path.  Also, any region can be shaped to an SVGPath using a CSS style of -fx-shape.  Internally, JavaFX (modena.css) usually uses layered backgrounds and -fx-shapes instead of borders.  However, you know your requirements best, and it might be that continuing with Path and your current solution would be best for you.

Since you're creating the text field and the border as two separate components, you need to rotate both of them. One way is to put them in a Group and rotate the Group (instead of the text field):
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField textField = new TextField("Hello, World!");
        textField.setStyle("-fx-padding: 8; -fx-max-width: 20; -fx-font-size: 18;" +
                "-fx-border-insets: 0; -fx-background-insets: 0; -fx-background-radius: 0; " +
                "-fx-border-style: none; -fx-background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5); -fx-min-width: 140");

//        textField.setRotate(-25);


        Path border = new Path();
        border.getElements().addAll(createBorder(textField, BorderLine.LEFT));
        border.getElements().addAll(createBorder(textField, BorderLine.TOP));
        border.getElements().addAll(createBorder(textField, BorderLine.RIGHT));
        border.getElements().addAll(createBorder(textField, BorderLine.BOTTOM));
        border.setManaged(false);
        border.setViewOrder(0);

        Group textBox = new Group(textField, border);
        textBox.setRotate(-25);

//        HBox root = new HBox(textField, border);
        HBox root = new HBox(textBox);
        root.setRotate(-25);
        root.setBackground(Background.fill(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        root.getTransforms().add(new Scale(2, 2));
        root.relocate(100, 100);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Custom Border");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 400));
        primaryStage.show();

        root.requestFocus();
    }

